# Local path not working

Tags: html, css

Hi my local path for my style sheet is not working.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
    <head>
        <rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\marinejoe30\Desktop\tyler_site\css\mystyle.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/php; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: How are you running it? I.e are you just running it from disk, and the address bar shows something like `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/hometek/`, or are you running it via a server on localhost - i.e the url looks like `localhost/hometek` ? If it's the 2nd one, you can't do that - you have to give a relative address. Looking at the page in the debugger (F12) should show you the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as the `<rel>` tag. Additionally, you had two `<html>` tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\marinejoe30\Desktop\tyler_site\css\mystyle.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/php; charset=utf-8" />
```

Running this through an [HTML validator](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+validator&oq=html+validator&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i60j69i65l3j69i60.1102j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would have saved you some time from posting on here. Please utilize resources before requesting help from the community in the future.

Comment: Yes, that's right - there is no `rel` **tag** - but that's not what's shown. It's a `<link>` tag, with a `rel` **attribute** - perfectly legal html.

Comment: @enhzflep I think you may be missing something... Look at his original markup

Comment: @stackover You may need to workout a relative path. Or try using forward clashes.